# Commas with dates

Tags: commas

Would you use a comma or not after 12 in the following sentence?

I've got this MRI report dated June 12 of 2017.

I've got this MRI report dated June 12, of 2017.

I know if the word "of" is not used there needs to be a comma, but it looks cleaner to me without the comma when the word of is used.  I'm just not sure if it's correct.

Comment: There is no 'need' to use a comma in the way you say: it is [merely a style choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202379/dates-and-commas). I'm not sure that 'I've got this MRI report dated June 12 of 2017.' is in a style sufficient people use for a style guide to recommend it, with or without the comma. Internet examples seem to prefer no comma.

Comment: Thank you! I prefer it without as well but didn't want to be incorrect.