# When wording a date where the month and year are seperate from the day, should the month have a comma? (See example.)

Tags: commas, dates

Notice the following text:

> “How old are you, anyway?” she asked.
>
> “Thirteen as of the twenty‐sixth of **July** 2004,” he stated proudly.

Should "July" have a comma here? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dates and commas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202379/dates-and-commas) (the answer and appended comment).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Not necessarily, as those examples follow the month-day-year format, not my example's "day OF"-month-year format. (Also, the example I'm using is for a U.S. book, not U.K.) This is why I wonder if the day should be ignored, making the month and year parallel the following: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/is-month-year-or-month-year-the-more-common-form-of-punctuation-in-print-pu

Comment: 'This is a matter of style choice rather than 'rules', so 'Yes, a comma is a MUST.' is like telling people which cola they MUST buy.'

Comment: A quick Google search for ["3rd of July 2007"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=1-2NXsXOJNPhxgOjzLGoCQ&q=%223rd+of+July+2007%22&oq=%223rd+of+July+2007%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQCBAeOgQIABBHOggIABAIEAcQHkoLCBcSBzEwLTlnNzBKCggYEgYxMC0yZzRQ080BWJ3YAWCA2wFoAHACeACAAUOIAYQCkgEBNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiFlrzTktnoAhXTsHEKHSNmDJUQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) shows 'no comma' seems the favoured choice, but the comma is found on occasion. You could try other similar searches and draw your own conclusions. I've tried one other, with similar results.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of style.  I would use the comma.